# activerecord: value isn't saved

Tags: ruby, activerecord, jruby

I work with activerecord in many projects but have never experienced this kind of problem.
Here is my class

```
class Ondon < ActiveRecord::Base
  self.table_name    = $rdms_3ondon_table
  self.sequence_name = $rdms_3ondon_sequence
end
```

I create a record like this

```
Ondon.create(:nr=>member.nr,
               :dossier_nr=>dosnr,
               :cre_dt=>Time.now, 
               :rowversion=>1,
               :status=>4
               )
```

But the value inserted for status is always 0, no matter what value i feed to the create.
The other fields are inserted fine.

When i activate the debugger is see in the sql that the value 0 is inserted.

Is status some kind of reserved word ? Unfortunately i can't change the name of this field.
Does anyone have a suggestion/sollution fo this ?

Comment: What is the type of the `status` column? Is it perhaps not an integer (INT) type?

Comment: Why are you declaring things like `$rdms_3ondon_table` as globals? That's really strange.

Comment: the type of status is number and i use the global because i can't use my configuration hash @conf['rdms_3ondon_table'] in an activerecord class, so i assign it to a global variable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found it.
The precision of the field status with type number in the oracle table was 1, in which case activerecords handles it like a boolean field (0=false, 1=true), my value of 4 was just disregarded.
I elevated the precision to 6 (don't know the rules about that) and now the insert works fine.

Is this a bug in activerecord ? I wouldn't know..